# SpringBootApplication Unable to get data from new table

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a spring boot application that is working with all the old code. I have added a new table that I am unable to get data from. The rest of the app works just fine. I'm able to login and do things which means the application connects to the database, it's just the new table I can't get data from. I'm adding the code into existing classes (though I want to pull it out if I can get this working).

I added the table manually. And added data to it. I can query the table from the CLI and get results back.

```
CREATE TABLE Eop_Information (
   id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   employer_als_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   sftp_directory varchar(24),
   eop_filename_pattern varchar(16),
   PRIMARY KEY(id),
   FOREIGN KEY (employer_als_id) REFERENCES Employer(employer_als_id)
);
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
})
@EnableScheduling
public class AlsApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(AlsApp.class, args);
   }

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
      return builder.sources(AlsApp.class);
   }
}
```

My HibernateConfig.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.als")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.als.bo")
public class HibernateConfig {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateConfig.class);

    @Value("${db.driverClassName}")
    private String dbDriverClassName;
    @Value("${db.database}")
    private String dbDatabaseType;
    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String dbUrl;
    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String dbUsername;
    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String dbPassword;
    @Value("${db.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
    private String dbHibernateDdlAuto;
    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String dbShowSql;
    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}")
    private String c3p0MinSize;
    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}")
    private String c3p0MaxSize;
    @Value("${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}")
    private String c3p0Timeout;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;
    @Value("${db.connection.pool_size}")
    private String connectionPoolSize;
    @Value("${hibernate.generate.statistics}")
    private String statistics;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.als");
        sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(EopInformation.class);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);

        log.info("Datasource created. {}", dataSource.getUrl());

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", dbHibernateDdlAuto);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", dbShowSql);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("spring.jpa.database", dbDatabaseType);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("connection.pool_size", connectionPoolSize);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect.storage_engine", "innodb");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", statistics);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(C3P0_TIMEOUT, c3p0Timeout);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(C3P0_MIN_SIZE, c3p0MinSize);
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(C3P0_MAX_SIZE, c3p0MaxSize);

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

EopInformation class

```
package com.als.bo;
// imports omitted
@Entity(name = "EopInformation")
@Table(name = "Eop_Information")
@NamedQueries(value = {
    @NamedQuery(name = "EopInformation.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM EopInformation e")
})
public class EopInformation {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long id;
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "employer_als_id")
   private Employer employer;
   @Column(name = "sftp_directory")
   private String sftpDirectory;
   @Column(name = "eop_filename_pattern")
   private String eopFilenamePattern;

   // Getters and Setters omitted
}
```

Service class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(Userdao userdao, S3FileService fileservice) {
       this.userdao = userdao;
       this.fileService = fileservice;
    }

    @Override
    public void process() {
       logger.info("Begin processing EOP Files.");
       long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       try {
           List<EopInformation> eopSftpList = userdao.getEOPFilenamePatterns();
           logger.info("Eop Information size: " + eopSftpList.size());
       
       // Code omitted
```

Dao class. I added the two methods to see if one would work but neither are getting any results.

```
@Repository
public class UserdaoImpl implements Userdao {

    @Autowired
    public UserdaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory, DataSource dataSource) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<EopInformation> getEOPFilenamePatterns() {
        try {
            logger.info("Begin");
            List<EopInformation> eopInformationListH = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                eopInformationListH = hibernateQuery();
            }
            logger.info("Hibernate result size: " + eopInformationListH.size());

            List<EopInformation> eopInformationList = new ArrayList<>();
            eopInformationList = datasourceQuery();
            logger.info("Datasource result size: " + eopInformationList.size());
            return eopInformationList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception getting SFTP EOP data . {}", e.getMessage(), e);
            return new ArrayList<>(0);
        }
    }

    private List<EopInformation> hibernateQuery() {
        try {
            Session session = getCurrentSession();
            session.clear();
            logger.info("Begin hibernate query userdao");
            String query = "SELECT e FROM EopInformation e";

            Query<EopInformation> q = session.createQuery(query, EopInformation.class);
            List<EopInformation> results = q.list();
            return results;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in Hibernate Query. {}", e.getMessage(), e);
            return new ArrayList<>(0);
        }
    }

    private List<EopInformation> datasourceQuery() {
        logger.info("Begin datasource query userdao");
        String query = "SELECT e.eop_filename_pattern, e.sftp_directory FROM Eop_Information e";
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
             java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
             ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {

            List<EopInformation> eopInformationList = new ArrayList<>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                logger.info("Looping");
                String filename = rs.getString("eop_filename_pattern");
                String directory = rs.getString("sftp_directory");
                EopInformation eop = new EopInformation();
                eop.setEopFilenamePattern(filename);
                eop.setSftpDirectory(directory);
                eopInformationList.add(eop);
            }
            return eopInformationList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception getting Eop Information. {}", e.getMessage(), e);
            return new ArrayList<>(0);
        }
    }
}
```

pom

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.als</groupId>
    <artifactId>ALS</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>My Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework-version>5.2.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.30</org.slf4j-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.860</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3control</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-translate-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.92</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung</groupId>
            <artifactId>lutung</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.21</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>target</webappDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>
</project>
```

My logs look like

```
dao.UserdaoImpl - Begin
dao.UserdaoImpl - Begin hibernate query userdao
dao.UserdaoImpl - Hibernate result size: 0
dao.UserdaoImpl - Begin datasource query userdao
dao.UserdaoImpl - Datasource result size: 0
service.UserServiceImpl - Eop Information size: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was user error. there's nothing wrong with the code.